# PostGIS install issues

Tags: postgis, installation, debian

I'm running Debian 12 and PostgreSQL 16 and trying to install PostGIS.  At this point when I run `apt-get install postgis` I receive:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
postgis is already the newest version (3.4.2+dfsg-1.pgdg120+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 90 not upgraded.

When I run `create extension postgis`, I receive:
Could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/16/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory.extension "postgis" is not available.

I'm relatively new to the Linux world so hoping for some guidance on how/where to start diagnosing this.

Comment: Not on debian, but ubuntu. What about `sudo apt install postgresql-16-postgis-3` or `postgresql-postgis`. What's the content of `/usr/share/postgresql/16/extension/`?

Comment: Yes sudo apt install postgresql-16-postgis-3 worked thank you!